# ActionCable Continuous Connect/Disconnect Loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actioncable

My rails application is using the ActionCable gem, configured as a simple chat application with one channel.

The close event keeps getting called, then reopened continuously.  My Rails server is seeing the connection properly; the loop is happening in the browser/Javascript.

```
 Connection.prototype.events = {
      message: function(event) {
        var identifier, message, ref;
        ref = JSON.parse(event.data), identifier = ref.identifier, message = ref.message;
        return this.consumer.subscriptions.notify(identifier, "received", message);
      },
      open: function() {
        this.disconnected = false;
        return this.consumer.subscriptions.reload();
      },
      close: function() {
        return this.disconnect();
      },
      error: function() {
        return this.disconnect();
      }
    };
```

Has anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: I had a similar issue, it turned out for me to be a massive garbage collection that would take over 8 seconds or more causing the client to miss the ping. I was running firefox dev edition and it turned out there was a memory leak where firefox was consuming 8gb of memory.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was wrong with this? I'm having this issue too.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using a server other than thin. I had this issue and banged my head against my keyboard for 3 days until trying a different server (puma) and was able to solve my issue. 
https://github.com/puma/puma